# Spring boot, error defining bean from same interface and class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class that define a list of zipcodes. In my Application class I define two objects of the same class and interface but with different information from application.yml

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "catalog.city1")
    public CatalogConfiguration city1() {
        return new Catalog();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "catalog.city2") 
    public CatalogConfiguration city2() {
        return new Catalog();
    }
}
```

When I want to use one like that...

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("city1")
CatalogConfiguration myCity;
```

...I get this error:

> No qualifying bean of type [] is defined: expected single matching
>   bean but found 2

I checked all documentation that I could, but I didn't found where it's my mistake.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined 2 beans of same type. Spring boot will simply override second bean over the first. And the way you are referencing the beans is by name. So I guess what you need to do is @Qualifier at the bean definition too with the same alias as city1 and city2. Or do it like @Bean('')

Comment: Hi Himanshu, thanks for your answer. 

I tried as you say but it doesn't work:

Comment: Can you post a more detailed stacktrace, and the new code changes you made. Bean name is not mentioned just [], maybe something is overlooked.

Comment: Hi Himanshu, It's just like you say. I prepared a demo to check your solution and it's work. I must be other thing.

Here I leave a little demo working project with your solution: https://github.com/fforcen/spring-boot-inject-demo